# Codeigniter - no input file specified - Why "?" solves this?

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

I had a problem with message `no input file specified`.

I found on stackoverflow's topic that to solve this change

`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]` to `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]`

Added question mark after index.php

And it worked.

Everything looks like:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

But why this worked? What this added question mark after `index.php` actually do and mean? Why this makes everything works?

I was looking and searching for this answer on all topics like this and I didn;t find anything that answers my question.

I only found that it `probably` works and is needed because of index.php not being in root directoryl, but I am not sure about this.

My directories are like:

```
/ (root folder)
--->application (app folder of framework)
--->myDomain.dx.am (my domain folder)
-------->index.php
-------->.htaccess (htaccess here)
-------->other_files
...................
--->system (system folder of framework)
```

I seek only for this answer, I am curious and I wanna know why does this work and how?

Comment: You probably need to tag with "Apache" so people with good Apache experience will tell you, but it all comes down to server config, and maybe even the specific version of Apache that the server is using.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please follow some step:

1. goto application/config/config.php :
   replace `$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';` to `$config['index_page'] = '';`
   and 
   `$config['uri_protocol']    = 'REQUEST_URI';` to `$config['uri_protocol']   = 'AUTO';`
2. enable rewrite mode by
    `sudo a2enmod rewrite`
   then
   `service apache2 restart`
3. if you'd like, you can use the following .htaccess file.

`<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>`

Answer (score 0):

1. The answer might be very long as this is related upon two major things. First one is the Apache Server's way to send the browsing URL request to the php code. And second one is to understand the MVC architechture of the CodeIgniter along with routing.
2. Most of mvc php frameworks have entry point is index.php to handle the routing requests. All we know the importance of pretty urls and we try to avoid ugly  routing urls, mostly which have name of controller and methods(in case of codeigniter or any other mvc).
3. So even we have pretty url the actually execution is done by the ugly url behind the scean. Mostly we define them in the Routes.php file for codeigniter 4. So with pretty url also handling of browser URl request either from user or from form submission or api are server wth ugly url and urgly urls have the index.php file and some get and post parameters. Always we have Controller name and Method the function in the Controller to be executed is given with help of symbols "?" and "&"
4. Another factor is the version Apache used with your hosting provider and the Operating System of your hosting.